# PowerShell script will run in Windows ISE, but not Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, powershell

I'm having some trouble trying to run a PowerShell script through Visual Studio and a program written in VB.NET.
The program in question has no issues running other PowerShell scripts through similar routines.

The Below script will work fine when run in both Windows PowerShell ISE and Visual Studio Code.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -force
Import-Module pwps_dab -force
$AdminPwd = ConvertTo-SecureString '123456789' -AsPlainText -Force
New-pwlogin -UserName 'Admin' -Password $AdminPwd -DatasourceName 'perpw1.com.au:Per_Pwise_new'
            
$FolderPath = 'Archives\1800 - 1899\1899\'
$PWfolders = Get-PWFolders -FolderPath $FolderPath -Verbose
$ProjectAccessString  = '----r------'
$DocumentAccessString = '----r--R---'
foreach($folder in $PWfolders){
    $UAC = $Folder | Get-PWFolderSecurity | Where-Object -Property InheritingFrom -eq 'none (folder own permissions)'
    foreach($item in $UAC){
        $Splat_Update = @{
        InputFolder = $folder
        MemberType = $item.Type
        MemberName = $item.Name
    }
    If ($item.SecurityType -eq 'Document'){
        $Splat_Update.DocumentSecurity = $true
        $Splat_Update.MemberAccessString = $DocumentAccessString
    } else {
        $Splat_Update.FolderSecurity = $true
        $Splat_Update.MemberAccessString = $ProjectAccessString
    }
    Update-PWFolderSecurity @Splat_Update -Verbose
    Update-PWFolderSecurity -InputFolder $folder -MemberType 'g' -MemberAccess 'fc' -MemberName 'Administrator' -DocumentSecurity -FolderSecurity
    }
}
```

When i try to run the same method in Visual Studio (whilst adding the required code to get VS to handle the commands) i receive the error

```
    Public Sub UpdateUACtoReadOnly(ByVal sFolderPath As String)
    Try
        Using MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
            MyRunSpace.Open()
            Using MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -force")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module pwps_dab -force")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$AdminPwd = ConvertTo-SecureString '123456789' -AsPlainText -Force")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("New-pwlogin -UserName 'Admin' -Password $AdminPwd -DatasourceName 'perpw1.com.au:Per_Pwise_new'")

                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$FolderPath = 'Archives\1800 - 1899\1899\'")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$PWfolders = Get-PWFolders -FolderPath $FolderPath -Verbose")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$ProjectAccessString  = '----r------'")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$DocumentAccessString = '----r--R---'")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("foreach($folder in $PWfolders){")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$UAC = $Folder | Get-PWFolderSecurity | Where-Object -Property InheritingFrom -eq 'none (folder own permissions)'")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("foreach($item in $UAC){")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Splat_Update = @{")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("InputFolder = $folder")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("MemberType = $item.Type")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("MemberName = $item.Name")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("}")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("If ($item.SecurityType -eq 'Document'){")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Splat_Update.DocumentSecurity = $true")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Splat_Update.MemberAccessString = $DocumentAccessString")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("} else {")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Splat_Update.FolderSecurity = $true")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Splat_Update.MemberAccessString = $ProjectAccessString")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("}")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Update-PWFolderSecurity @Splat_Update -Verbose")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Update-PWFolderSecurity - InputFolder $folder -MemberType 'g' -MemberAccess 'fc' -MemberName 'Administrator' -DocumentSecurity -FolderSecurity")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("}")
                MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("}")

                MyPipeline.Invoke()
                MyPipeline.Dispose()
            End Using
            MyRunSpace.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in Running Powershell Script:UpdateUACtoReadOnly" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End
    Finally

    End Try
End Sub
```

[image]

Whilst i know the error sounds pretty straight forward. I can't see where to add the extra }, all the brackets are closed already. Just for arguments sake, i put an extra } at the end of the script and had the same result. Considering the scripts run in ISE and VScode, i'm pretty lost as to what the issue could be? Is there something extra that Visual Studio requires that the PowerShell ISE's don't? Im at a bit of a loss considering the other scripts work the same way, granted this is a bit longer than the others, but isn't that different.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a step back, and look at your ISE code that is working, and then explicitly compare that to the VS quoting you are using, and see where your quoting is off, thus generating errors.

Comment: I have tried this. I have also used a compare tool (Beyond Compare) and NotePad++ to make sure the indentations were all correct. I can't see where there needs to have a closed bracket?

Comment: You want to call `AddScript` _once_, supply the whole script at once.

Comment: You are not running as Admin when inside VS.  Either run the exe file outside VS, or start VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Running as Admin made no difference

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen
I have tried to consolidate the script into far fewer lines but still has the same result. The other scripts for other methods work the same way with no issues. It's like theres an issue with the script, but I cant find it and neither can VScode or ISE?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the problem is with the space between `- InputFolder`

```
            MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Update-PWFolderSecurity - InputFolder $folder -MemberType 'g' -MemberAccess 'fc' -MemberName 'Administrator' -DocumentSecurity -FolderSecurity")
```

Comment: I did see that Typo after posting but unfortunately it didnt fix the issue. Still havent found a solution yet

Comment: Try catching this error in your code to get more error information.

Answer (score 0):

I parked this project for a bit but came back to it recently. The solution came from @Mathias R. Jessen quote about calling the AddScript once.
I created a string separated by "Environment.NewLine" to build it as per above, then called the AddScript at the end and it worked.

Comment: Please consider adding a code snippet example to clarify your answer.